# Ошибка в тексте о технических работах

Tags: дефект, локализация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да и запятая после "обычно" не требуется.

Comment: Вроде ещё запятая после "обычно" лишняя?

Comment: @andreymal чёт слишком долго это всё длит**Ь**ся %)